# When exactly is the log file closed (Linq to SQL)

Tags: linq-to-sql

I log all generated sql as below. Now I want to log any exceptions to the same file.

```
StreamWriter mLogFile = new StreamWriter(LogFilePath,true){AutoFlush=true};

try
{
MyDataContext mdc = new MyDataContext();
mLogFile.WriteLine(CurrentDateString);
mdc.Log = mLogFile;
BLAH BLAH DB STUFF
mdc.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(Exception x)
{

}
```

All I want is when there is an exception, I want to add exception info in to the Log file. 
Not sure if it is ok to just writeLine to the file in the catch block. When exactly does the datacontext release the log file? when submitchanges returns? what happens when there is an exception? Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data context does not take ownership of the log. You are responsible for releasing it. So I would suggest wrapping the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block. So to answer your question: yes you can write to the log in the `catch` block (assuming you haven't disposed of the `StreamWriter` by then).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that the db I guess I can add a finally block and do dispose and close on streamwriter explicitly.